# Calculating the mean and standard deviation of a Gaussian mixture model of two curves

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, game-theory, gaussian

An ELO rating is a Gaussian curve with a mean and a standard deviation. Assuming there are two such ratings that belong to the same player (he's using two separate online identities so he has two separate ratings) - How would I best merge the two curves into one curve representing the ELO of the persona?

Extending the question based on comments below:

The rating's mean is the approximate skill of the player, and the standard deviation is the level of confidence of the system in the skill approximation.

The suggested model is to use a Gaussian mixture model with some probability of picking each of the identities, and then calculate the mean and standard deviation of the resulting distribution. I know the mixed distribution is not Gaussian, but I need just two parameters, so this is what I am after.

**In short**

How do you calculate the mean and standard deviation of a Gaussian mixture model of two Gaussian curves *($\mu_1$, $\sigma_1$)*, *($\mu_2$, $\sigma_2$)* with probability of *p* and *(1-p)* for each curve?

Comment: You can consider a *Gaussian mixture model*, using weights $p$ and $1-p$ (the probabilities of the player using each of his identities, which would be $0.5$ and $0.5$ if they are used equally likely). A Gaussian mixture model would model the case where your player selects one of his personas with some probability, and given that he has picked a particular one, his rating is generated from the Gaussian distribution of that persona. See e.g. [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/gaussian-mixture-model/) for further reading.

Comment: Would the mixture be Gaussian as well? Because if not, I need to approximate it with a Gaussian curve with its own mean and standard deviation.

Comment: No, it won't be.

Comment: If I do a GMM and then take the mean and standard deviation of the resulting distribution and call it the "merged ELO" would that be a good approach?

Comment: Maybe. Kind of depends what you need here. (E.g. why do you need a Gaussian result? Is it because you need an ELO format, which must be Gaussian?) If someone is picking from two personas with very different means, you can end up having their GMM be clearly bimodal.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert but the software I'm working on represents ELO as a mean and a standard deviation, and I need to find some reasonable way to merge two (mu,sigma)'s into one. The mu is the approximate skill, and the sigma is the "level of confidence" in it. The assumption is that the means of the two identities are not very different (subjective)

Comment: OK. Probably worth doing this then for simplicity. You can analytically derive what the mean and variance has to be if you know the mean and variance of each persona, and are willing to assume what is the probability of each persona being used (don't even need them to be Gaussian to do this).

Comment: I would like to do that, can you provide an answer that I can use? A formula? Either make it parameterized on the probability for either persona, or just assume equal probability for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$Assume that the two personas are represented by distributions $X_1\sim \N\left(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2\right)$ and $X_2\sim \N\left(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2\right)$, where $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k^2$ are the mean and variance respectively of $X_k$, for $k=1,2$. Assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

We can model the overall persona as coming from $X_1$ with some probability $p$, or coming from $X_2$ otherwise (with probability $1-p$).

That is, if $Z$ is the overall persona, then $Z = IX_1 + (1-I)X_2$, where $I$ is a random variable that is $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$, and $I,X_1,X_2$ are independent.

In this case, $Z$ (the overall persona) is modelled as a [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://brilliant.org/wiki/gaussian-mixture-model/), with probability density function $f_Z(z) = pf_{X_{1}}(z)+(1-p)f_{X_{2}}(z)$, where $f_{X_{k}}$ is the probability density function of $X_k$, $k=1,2$.

If you just want the mean and variance of the overall persona $Z$ (to use for a Gaussian model), the formulas are:

> $\Bbb{E}[Z] = p \mu_1 + (1-p)\mu_2$

and

> $\Var(Z) = p\sigma_1^2 +(1-p)\sigma_2^2 + p(1-p)\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\right)^2.$

---

Some hints to proving the formulas for the mean and variance of $Z$ are to recall the following facts:

1. $\E[Z] = \E[\E[Z\mid I]]$ by the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)
2. $\Var(Z) = \E[\Var(Z\mid I)] + \Var(\E[Z\mid I])$ by the [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)
3. If $Y$ is a random variable that takes value $a$ with probability $p$ and value $b$ with probability $1-p$ (where $a,b$ are constants), then $\E[Y] = pa+(1-p)b$ and $\Var(Y) = p(1-p)(a-b)^2$.

Comment: Decades ago, there was a period during which the best chess-playing computers ("engines") did seem to have dual persona, winning almost every game against IM's (International Masters) and losing almost every game against GM's (Grand Masters). Any human who almost always defeats IM's would be a strong GM capable of holding his own against GM's.